# Mongodb: Push element in multiple nested array with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I push value into multiple nested array with specific conditions? 
I have a document like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "class_a",
    "students": [
      {
        "_id": "1a",
        "name": "John",
        "grades": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "1b",
        "name": "Katie",
        "grades": []
      },
      {
        "_id": "1c",
        "name": "Andy",
        "grades": []
      },
      
    ]
  }
]
```

Query to insert into nested array. (Not sure what is missing here)

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "class_a",
  "students": {
    $elemMatch: {
      "_id": {
        "$in": [
          "1a",
          "1b"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $push: {
    "students.$.grades": "A+"
  }
})
```

Got the following result. But I was expecting both `John` and `Katie` have `A+` in `grades`

```
[
  {
    "_id": "class_a",
    "students": [
      {
        "_id": "1a",
        "grades": ["A+"],
        "name": "John"
      },
      {
        "_id": "1b",
        "grades": [],
        "name": "Katie"
      },
      {
        "_id": "1c",
        "grades": [],
        "name": "Andy"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "class_a",
    "students": [
      {
        "_id": "1a",
        "grades": ["A+"],
        "name": "John"
      },
      {
        "_id": "1b",
        "grades": ["A+"],
        "name": "Katie"
      },
      {
        "_id": "1c",
        "grades": [],
        "name": "Andy"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Mongo playground to test the code](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aK-jwmW8fsV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$[<identifier>]` to update only the items that match a condition. Your first `{}` is to find the relevant **documents**, while the `arrayFilters` is to find the relevant **items** inside the document nested array:

```
db.collection.update(
  {_id: "class_a", students: {$elemMatch: {_id: {$in: ["1a", "1b"]}}}},
  {$push: {"students.$[item].grades": "A+"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"item._id": {$in: ["1a", "1b"]}}], upsert: true}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XlkOvRSIOFr)

Comment: This is a good solution also, I would have mark this is the answer if I can mark more than one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is the first answer and a better one

Comment: Ok then, can you justify how is this solution better? Like is this going to run faster in terms of performance?

Comment: It is justified in the explanation and on the comments of the other answer...

Comment: After reading the second time, I agree that your solution might be better performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use [arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) for these otherwse it'll only match the first entity. You don't need to use $elemMatch at all.

Playground - https://mongoplayground.net/p/_7y89KB83Ho

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "class_a"
},
{
  $push: {
    "students.$[students].grades": "A+"
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "students._id": {
        "$in": [
          "1a",
          "1b"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: There is a need to use `$elemMatch` in order to find the relevant document. Your answer will try the `arrayFilters` on all items on **all** documents

Comment: Are you sure? I'm happy to be wrong and learn, but I was under the impression that an `arrayFilter` would be all that is needed. The playground version works as expected.  Ah, I see what you mean, the initial match (`_id:"class_a"`) should limit the ATTEMPT to apply the $push and $arrayFilters, eg, if there were no record of `1a` or `1b`, it would still ATTEMPT to apply the array filters. I would be interested to know the actual performance impact of this. I think I would prefer this option in terms of readability anyway. But I get what you're saying. Thanks

Comment: In terms of readability, this solution is better. Didn't knew we can use arrayFilter like this. Thank you so much!